# Ruby grouping hash

Tags: ruby

```
people = [
  { "name" => "Mary", "sport" => "squash", "fruit" => "blackberry" },
  { "name" => "Lauren", "sport" => "squash", "fruit" => "orange" },
  { "name" => "Isla", "sport" => "weightlifting", "fruit" => "banana" },
  { "name" => "Sam", "sport" => "cycling", "fruit" => "orange" },
  { "name" => "Govind", "sport" => "squash", "fruit" => "banana" },
  { "name" => "Awad", "sport" => "weightlifting", "fruit" => "kiwi" },
  { "name" => "Will", "sport" => "cycling", "fruit" => "blackberry" }
]

sport = {
  squash: [],
  weightlifting: [],
  cycling: []
}
```

What would be the simplest way of grouping people by their chosen sport?

```
I.e.

sport = {
  squash: ["Mary", "Lauren", "Govind"],
  weightlifting: ["Isla", "Awad"],
  cycling: ["Sam", "Will"]
}
```

It's the fact that there are hashes inside hashes which is confusing me. I'm currently playing around with the below but no cigar yet.

```
sport[:squash].push(people.select {|k,v| k if v == "squash"})
```

Answer (score 2):

anything like this?

```
people.group_by { |person| person['sport'] }
      .transform_values { |people| people.map { |person| person['name'] } }
=> {"squash"=>["Mary", "Lauren", "Govind"], "weightlifting"=>["Isla", "Awad"], "cycling"=>["Sam", "Will"]}
```

I've used [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), read the doc about them. `group_by` is called on an `Enumerable` (that's a module included in `Array`, `Hash` and others) and `transform_values` is called on an `Hash`. Execute one method at time to understand better what's happening.

Comment: Thank you!!  Any chance you'd be able to explain how that works?

Comment: i've added links to the doc :)

Comment: Note that the keys of `sport` are symbols (a nuisance, eh?).

Comment: wanderingnowhere, the first step in this calculation is as follows.
`people.group_by { |person| person['sport'] } #=>
{"squash"=>[{"name"=>"Mary", "sport"=>"squash", "fruit"=>"blackberry"}, {"name"=>"Lauren", "sport"=>"squash", "fruit"=>"orange"}, {"name"=>"Govind", "sport"=>"squash", "fruit"=>"banana"}], "weightlifting"=>[{"name"=>"Isla", "sport"=>"weightlifting", "fruit"=>"banana"}, {"name"=>"Awad", "sport"=>"weightlifting", "fruit"=>"kiwi"}], "cycling"=>[{"name"=>"Sam", "sport"=>"cycling", "fruit"=>"orange"}, {"name"=>"Will", "sport"=>"cycling", "fruit"=>"blackberry"}]}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill out the hash `sport` as follows.

```
people.each { |g| sport[g["sport"].to_sym] << g["name"] }
```

```
sport
  #=> {:squash=>["Mary", "Lauren", "Govind"],
  #    :weightlifting=>["Isla", "Awad"],
  #    :cycling=>["Sam", "Will"]}
```

---

If the keys of `sport` are not known and are to be derived from `people`, one can do that as follows.

```
people.each_with_object({}) do |g,sport|
  key_sym = g["sport"].to_sym
  sport[key_sym] = [] unless sport.key?(key_sym)
  sport[key_sym] << g["name"]
end
  #=> {:squash=>["Mary", "Lauren", "Govind"],
  #    :weightlifting=>["Isla", "Awad"],
  #    :cycling=>["Sam", "Will"]}
```

It would be common to see this shortened in one of two ways:

```
people.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  (h[g["sport"].to_sym] ||= []) << g["name"]
end
```

or

```
people.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g["sport"].to_sym] << g["name"]
end
```

The latter uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that employs a block.

Comment: The approach that immediately comes to mind for me is people.each{|x| sport[x["sport"].to_sym] << x["name"]} which is almost identical to your first example. I'm sure you have a good reason for using each_with_object though. I'm curious what that reason is though.  Your reasons for use in the rest of your examples is clear, just not the first example.

Comment: @MichaelB, good point. I agree, `each` would be better. I'll change that. I used `each_with_object` so that the expression would return `sport`.

Comment: `#each` works if `sport` already exists and we want to mutate it. If `sport` is not already defined, then `#each_with_object` can build that hash.